# jquery mobile button :active(css) too slow

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm making  android hybrid app with jquery mobile v1.4. 
And when I'm pressing(tap) the button, it's too slow change to :active css.

This is my sample code

```
<a href="btn">Button</a>

<style>
.btn { display:block; width:100px; height:30px; background:gray }
.btn:active {  background:red; }
</style>
```

I searched some script that it makes more faster, but this is not work to me.

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 500
});
```

Is there any way to make it more faster ?